# Eliminar Filas Duplicadas

Tags: vba

Quiero prepararme un pequeño programa para que me elimine las filas duplicadas. Lo podría hacer manualmente con la opción de Quitar duplicados pero quiero programarlo para que con un `call` luego lo pueda meter en un botón junto con otra ejecución.
He utilizado este pero me va lentísimo y creo que es porque se pone a recorrer todas las celdas... A ver si alguien me echa una mano!

```
Option Explicit

Sub EliminarDuplicados()


'Elimina filas duplicadas sólo si son consecutivas,

    Dim Rango As Range
    Dim filaAnterior As Range, fila As Range
    Dim indice As Integer

    Set Rango = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
    Set filaAnterior = Rango.Rows(1)
    indice = 2

    Do While indice <= Rango.Rows.Count
        Set fila = Rango.Rows(indice)
        If RangosIguales(fila, filaAnterior) Then
            fila.Delete
        Else
            Set filaAnterior = fila
            indice = indice + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub`
```

Comment: Esto sería mejor con un ejemplo en datos. Cual es tu input y el output deseado. En cualquier caso, ¿has probado a añadir `Application.ScreenUpdating=false` al principio de tu código?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método RemoveDuplicates, puede ser algo como esto.

**Opción 1**: Se obtiene rango mediante CurrentRegion

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestDuplicados()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nColumnas As Integer

    Set rng = Hoja1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

    nColumnas = rng.Columns.Count

    With rng
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=nColumnas, Header:=xlNo 'todas las columnas se toman en cuanta
        '.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo 'solo considera las dos primeras columnas
    End With

End Sub
```

`Columns:=nColumnas` aplica cuando todas las columnas se comparan para decidir si se considera como duplicado.

`Columns:=Array(1, 2)` sirve cuando se desea indicar los números de columna que se deben tomar en cuanta para decidir si es duplicado.

**Opción 2**: El rango se obtiene mediante otro método ( conteo de filas y columnas ).

```
Sub TestDuplicados()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nColumnas As Integer
    Dim nFilas As Long
    Dim strCol As String

    nColumnas = Hoja1.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    nFilas = Hoja1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    strCol = Split(Cells(, nColumnas).Address, "$")(1)

    Set rng = Hoja1.Range("A2:" & strCol & nFilas)

    With rng
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=nColumnas, Header:=xlNo 'todas las columnas se toman en cuanta
        '.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo 'solo considera las dos primeras columnas
    End With

End Sub
```

Adicionalmente, se debe cambiar `Header:=xlNo` a `Header:=xlYes` cuando el rango de datos contiene encabezados.

Comment: Este no me serviria porque está cogiendo el rango A2. Lo que tengo es una tabla que varia de dimensiones filasxcolumnas:

Set rng = Hoja1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

Comment: Lo probaste..? no esta tomando solo el rango A2, esta partiendo de A2 y se extiende según los datos que hay a su alrededor, aunque esta el problema que cuando hay filas o columnas sin datos en medio no tomara el rango completo, pero obtener el rango completo no es problema, lo que importa es la linea que toma ese rango y elimina duplicados.

Comment: Si me funciono, muchas graciass!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Este no me serviria porque está cogiendo el rango A2. Lo que tengo es una tabla que varia de dimensiones filasxcolumnas:

Set rng = Hoja1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

Comment: estas respondiendo a tu pregunta?

Comment: ostras ok, disculpame.